# Inside transparent border

Tags: html, css

I want to set a transparent border inside  around an image by using CSS. I can't find any way to do this.

here is the [link](http://imageshack.com/a/img809/2130/soqw.jpg) for my image with transparent inside border effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an easy task, since images are replaced elements and have quite some restrictions (pseudo-elements not working, inset box-shadow not working,...).

You have several options (there are probably more, I just list two):

Solution 1:
Make your image the background-image of an ordinary div and apply a border - this border will automatically overlap the image. Btw., you can use `background-clip` and `background-origin` to alter that behaviour.
Problem:
You need to know the dimensions of the image, to adjust the size of the div accordingly.

Solution 2:
Wrap your image into another element, and declare a pseudo-element to which you apply the borders.
Important are the `display:block` on the img and `position:relative` on the wrapper element.

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YTxGE/4/)

Comment: But here arise new problem. i have some text wrapping the image.but if i used display:inline-block for the wrapper div it allocate the space for the text. here is ([link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/189718598/index.html).).

Comment: @Rahat just declare `float` (left or right, whatever you prefer) on the wrapper div.

Comment: @Rahat You are welcome. If your issue is solved now, you can close the question by accepting the answer by ticking the green checkmark. Also if you find answers helpful e.g. Deekey's one, you can always upvote as many answers as you want.

Answer (score -1):

Use `box-shadow`

This CSS `box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 8px rgba(255, 16, 16, 0.45);`

You can do the thing amazingly  he he Enjoy It

http://jsfiddle.net/Q8d6V/3/

Comment: inset box-shadows don't work on images. On elements with background images you can as well use a normal border like i described in my solution.

Answer (score -2):

I can offer use 4 border-blocks with `position:absolute`. You can change style of each border. For exaple add shadow for left and top border

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phpowl/pHz7W/4/)